# Count sort in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, count

I am trying to implement a Count Sort algorithm in C, but it only sorts the first 4 elements and then it goes crazy.

I am using the wikipedia page (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countingsort) as orientation.

I am using an **external .txt file for the input**.

The txt file I tried contains the following numbers:

```
90, 38, 42, 34, 8, 0, 77, 1, 84, 5, 25, 72, 44, 42, 90, 63, 23
```

And the **result** is:

```
0, 1, 5, 8, 1836801184, 32767, 1343601744, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1696599910, -721405914, 33, 0, 1343602158
```

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "input_blatt01.h"

int MAX_LAENGE = 1000;
int MAX_VALUE = 100;
int i,k,j;
void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[]) 
{
    for (i=0; i<=len;i++)
    {
        count_array[i] = 0;
    }
    for (j=0; j<sizeof(input_array);j++)
    {
        count_array[input_array[j]] = count_array[input_array[j]] + 1;
    }
}

void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int len, int count_array[]) 
{
    k=0;
    for (j=0;j<sizeof(count_array);j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<count_array[j]; i++)
        {
            output_array[k] = j;
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Aufruf: %s <Dateiname>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s zahlen.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];

    int input_array[MAX_LAENGE];   
    int len = read_array_from_file(input_array, MAX_LAENGE, filename);

    printf("Unsortiertes Array:");
    print_array(input_array, len);
    int count_array[MAX_LAENGE];
    int output_array[MAX_LAENGE];
    count_sort_calculate_counts(input_array, len, count_array);
    count_sort_write_output_array(output_array, len, count_array);

    printf("Sortiertes Array:");
    print_array(output_array, len);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in count_sort_calculate_counts function.

`for (i=0; i<=len;i++)`

Did you mean i < len?

```
for (j=0; j<sizeof(input_array);j++)
```

sizeof doesn't do what you think it does. It will definitely not give you number of array elements but size of the variable input_array.

Answer (score 0):

This function is what you need:

```
void countingSort(int numbers[], int size)
{
    int count[RANGE];
    for (int i=0; i<RANGE; i++)
        count[i] = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        count[numbers[i]]++;

    int index = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<RANGE; i++)
    {
        while (count[i] > 0)
        {
            numbers[index] = i;
            index++;
            count[i]--;
        }
    }
}
```

It sorts the array `numbers`. the `RANGE` is the set to maximum value of your numbers. In your case:

```
#define RANGE 100
```